# How to fix **The value of "value" is out of range** error in protractor?

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor, browserstack

I am working the Angular 7 with Protractor for e2e automated test case along with am using browserstack for multiple browser testing. In my project I have image upload option for testing image upload I have used the following code.

```
const path = require('path'), remote = require('selenium-webdriver/remote');
browser.setFileDetector(new remote.FileDetector());
const displayCustomLogoTextBox = element(by.id('customLogoTextbox'));
const fileToUpload = 'test-logo.png' ,
absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);
displayCustomLogoTextBox.sendKeys(absolutePath);
applyBtn.click();
```

While testing with local chorme it working fine but when I am testing with browserstack it thorwing below error in this line.

```
displayCustomLogoTextBox.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

> *** Failed: The value of "value" is out of range. It must be >= -2147483648 and <= 2147483647. Received 2977340326 ***

Can anyone give me a quick solution to this?

Comment: At which line is the error thrown?

Comment: @TodorMinakov displayCustomLogoTextBox.sendKeys(absolutePath);

Comment: @ManikandanThangaraj
Did you happen to find a solution to this issue?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue.  Is this a node version issue?  I'm on node 10.16.0 and Protractor 5.4.2?

Comment: Have you found any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine when I downgraded my node to v7.7.3 since I was using protractor version 5.